# IsFileOpen() NeverSees File as Open?

Tags: ms-access, vba

In VBA (from MS Access) I am trying to determine if an XLS file is OPEN by calling the following function, sending the full path and filename:

```
Function IsFileOpen(FileName As String)

    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
        Case 0:    IsFileOpen = False
        Case 70:   IsFileOpen = True
        Case 53:   IsFileOpen = False ' File not found
        Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select

End Function
```

This routine only ever returns (0) - File Closed - regardless of the status of the file in question.  I have confirmed the path and filename are correct, constructed in Access as follows:

```
strPath = Left(CurrentDb.NAME, InStrRev(CurrentDb.NAME, "\"))
myFile = strPath & myInvID & "ChangeTemplate.xlsx"
```

Any thoughts what I might be missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Note:  Routine does see Err 53 - File Not Found.  I added that condition to the Case statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argh!  XLS was being saved with AccessMode := xlShared

The file always passed the LOCK test from this routine.

<< Topic is Closed >>